# ScaleImageLabel does not scale the image on bigger screens

Tags: codenameone

I'm using the ScaleImageLabel to display the image in the sidemenu. Image is scaling properly on smaller device screens but not scaling properly on bigger screens. Space will be displayed on both left and right sides of the image. Please advise if I need to apply any additional setting with ScaleImageLabel to scale it accordingly. I'm using JPEG. I have tried both FIT and FILL. FILL is making the image display in zoomed format and complete image is not visible. FIT display image properly on phones but display small image on tablets.

Comment: Without a picture of the result I can only guess but try `sl.setBackgroundType(Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED_FILL);`

Comment: This didnt work. Is there any specific size I have to use to display properly on all size devices. As of now image resolution is - 750 px * 300 px. Please advise.

Comment: Check the image in the component inspector. See the values for the width/height of `sl` as well as the margin/padding values. I'm guessing these are the cause of this.

Comment: Shai, I have verified the logo using component inspector. If I use "FILL", logo is zoomed and getting truncated and where as if I use "FIT"  logo display small on big screens. I have attached the logo in component inspector to show the details. Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is the limit of the aspect ratio scaling. The size allocated to the logo is the same as the preferred size of the logo. By default this is the actual size of the image.

So the logo doesn't have anywhere to "grow" vertically without distorting its shape or truncating. You can possibly override the preferred size method to return a more appropriate size. You can use a complex calculation about available size but I would recommend using something like millimeter sizes for a simpler implementation just tune this to your preference:

```
ScaleImageLabel sl = new ScaleImageLabel(Backend.instance.getLogo()) {
   protected Dimension calcPreferredSize() {
        int size = convertToPixels(10);
        return new Dimension(size, size);
   }
};
```

Comment: Shai, I'm trying to calculate the width available on Toolbar to display the image in the side menu. This is not scaling properly on all the devices. can you please provide the code to calculate the the available size to display for all the devices. I have updated the code which I have tried above. Please advise

Comment: Shai, Ihave tried both FIT and FILL. FILL is making the image dispaly in zoomed format and complete image is not visible. FIT display image properly on phones but display small image on tablets. Please advise.

Comment: You can use scale that deforms the image. All 3 options are the only options in existence (in programming not a Codename One limit). You can give different preferred size for tablets if you prefer.